FleetDM deployment
Has anyone deployed a FleetDM instance locally? I've tried both their (now apparently outdated) CentOS deploy steps and also docker composeing the official image, combined with MySQL and Redis. My problem is, I'm consistently getting the response Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server. when trying to visit and/or configure the installation.
Is there any way to resolve that HTTPS issue? I've already generated self-signed certificates, but the above response is consistent. It doesn't give me any option to ignore certificates in-browser, but does return a 200 when I requests.get("https://localhost:8080", verify=False) in REPL.

8080 is mostly the http port and used as it, you have to look for a ssl port imho.

That sounds like you're running into a situation where your FleetDM instance is expecting HTTPS connections but is being accessed via HTTP, which results in the "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server" error.
I'd need some logs to be sure, but I hope this solves it:
Make sure that your FleetDM configuration is set up correctly to handle HTTPS. If you’re using Docker Compose, check your docker-compose.yml and any associated configuration files.
That might involve setting environment variables or configuration options related to SSL/TLS. Review FleetDM’s documentation for details on how to configure HTTPS.
Update FleetDM environment variables
Makes sure that the environment variables related to FleetDM's server configuration are set correctly. This includes variables for SSL certificates and keys.
Example environment variables to check or add in your Docker Compose configuration might include:
environment:
  - FLEET_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
  - FLEET_SERVER_TLS_CERT=/path/to/your/cert.pem
  - FLEET_SERVER_TLS_KEY=/path/to/your/key.pem

If you’re using docker compose, ensure your docker-compose.yml reflects the correct configuration for HTTPS. For example, you may need to map the ports correctly and configure the FleetDM container to use HTTPS.
services:
  fleetdm:
    image: fleetdm/fleet:latest
    ports:
      - "443:443"  # Make sure you’re mapping HTTPS port correctly
    environment:
      - FLEET_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
      - FLEET_SERVER_TLS_CERT=/path/to/your/cert.pem
      - FLEET_SERVER_TLS_KEY=/path/to/your/key.pem
    volumes:
      - /path/to/your/certs:/certs

When you access the FleetDM instance, make sure you use https:// in the URL and not http://. Like this:
https://localhost:443

Make sure that the self-signed certificates you generated are valid and properly configured. Otherwise, it might not be recognized properly by the server. Make sure your self-signed certificate matches the private key and is correctly configured in FleetDM.
You should also check there’s no proxy or redirect configuration that could be causing issues. Sometimes, proxies might redirect traffic incorrectly, which can lead to HTTPS/HTTP mismatches.
Check the FleetDM logs for any errors or warnings related to HTTPS. Logs can often provide insight into what might be going wrong.
docker-compose logs fleetdm

Verify:
curl -v https://localhost:443
or
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443


If it works, please click on the checkmark icon next to the answer to accept the solution.
Good luck!

It was the part about exposing port 443 to the host. Once I did that, I could force a browser to accept the self-signed cert and proceed. It looks like FLEET_SERVER_PROTOCOL defaults to https? Because it works with or without that. But also, you don't need to go to localhost:443 in-browser or curl once this is configured, you can go to localhost:8080 (or whatever port you set+exposed for HTTP traffic).
